# How do you open the color picker in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

In Xcode I know how to access the color picker from the storyboard. But is there a shortcut to open it from anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add a shortcut, you can go to the Keybindings menu and add a shortcut there.

[image: Here's a scrreenshot in Xcode 10]

Answer (score 18):

Ah ok, I should have searched a little longer.

In the navbar `Edit` -> `Format` -> `Show colors`

Comment: Thanks. Totally not obvious and hard to find - under "Format" ??!!